# Asynchronous Pubnub calls block android ui thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, pubnub

I am trying to get the server time from pubnub with the time method

```
mPubnub.time(callback);
```

I suppose it is an asynchronous call then I have a waiting loop just after so I can wait for the result

```
time = -1;
mPubnub.time(callback);
while(time == -1);
```

In the call back I have

```
Callback callback = new Callback() {
    public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.toString());
            time = jsonArray.getLong(0) / 10000;
            return;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        time = 0;
    }

    public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
        Log.wtf("error/" + channel, error.toString());
        time = 0;
    }
};
```

All these calls are from `doInBackground` of an `AsyncTask`.  Why is it blocking my ui thread. Also calls to publish are also blocking my UI thread and I only call them from an  `AsyncTask`

Many people say the while loop blocks the UI thread but I don't understand why that loop in an AsyncTask would block the UI thread. It wasn't in the `onPostExecute` or `onProgressExecute`. It was in `doInBackground` and it shouldn't block the UI.

On the other hand removing the loop still blocks the UI thread

```
mPubnub.time(callback);
mPubnub.publish(channel, message, true, callback);
```

these simple calls block the UI thread and the application stops responding.

Answer (score 2):

This is blocking your UI thread:

```
while(time == -1);
```

Instead of doing that, you should handle the success/failure via the callback.  If the pubnub API takes a callback like this, it would appear as though it is already handling doing it on a background thread.  Just take the appropriate action inside the callback handlers.

Comment: even when i do, a simple publish is blocking the ui thread. I actually handle following the callbacks but i want to understand why a background task is blocking the UI thread

Comment: If you are doing a while loop like this, you are blocking the thread.

Comment: the while(time == -1) as stated is blocking your thread. Put a log message in there and you will see.

Comment: also...no need to create a new instance of the JSONArray..JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.toString()); .. instead just cast it down.

Comment: @FrederickBrock I get a ClassCastException and on debugging, i found that it is indeed a string.

Comment: @FrederickBrock Even when I don't put the loop the pubnub calls  (publish and time) blocks the UI thread

Comment: At this point I would suggest you provide all or most of your code.  The couple of snippets provided do not give enough context for us to help.  If the UI thread is blocking long enough, you'll get an ANR and a crash dump from the log.  The bottom line is that if you're calling the pubnub (or any other API) in a `doInBackground()` method, that will have no effect on the main (UI) thread.  You have to have some code on the UI thread which is blocking.

Comment: Facing same issue, have you got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

> while(time == -1);

This line blocks your UI Thread, because of this pointer will never updated by other thread, it's not a volatile variable.
You can use [Debug Bottle](https://github.com/kiruto/debug-bottle#block-canary) to detect UI Block codes in your project.